# Fromated user input in text area

Tags: playframework, wysiwyg, playframework-2.1

I have a play application. Until now, the application got backend user input as text in a textarea input field and this plain text was saved into the database.

Now requirments changed and it should be formated text like bold parts or links.

To keep it simple, can I use some control characters to mark certain formats in play?

For example, how could I show plain html in a play-template? If I use angle brackets it will be changed from `<` to `&lt;`

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty:

```
<p>
  @Html(article.content)    
</p>
```